# Gulp watch multiple folders

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, babeljs

In a project, during development, I want to

- Watch and recompile server side code with Babel (since I want to use "ES6" on Parse)
- Watch and recompile client side code with Browserify/Watchify

How can I do this? I could write 2 watch tasks, but I will have to open 2 terminal windows just to watch both these directories. Isit possible to do it in 1 gulp task? Like do 2 tasks?

Comment: I added an answer, but now I have a question, do you need help writing the tasks as well, or just the watch?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you want.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['directoryA/**/*.js', 'directoryB/js/**/*.js'], ['task']);
});
```

You can also add a more to the array if you want to watch other file types. IE: `'directoryA/**/*.html'`

If you want them to run two different tasks as you mention, change it to:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['directoryA/**/*.js'], ['taskA']);
    gulp.watch(['directoryB/**/*.js'], ['taskB']);
});
```

An example gulp task I have using *[Browerify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify)* and *[Babelify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babelify)*.

```
gulp.task('taskA', function() {
    return browserify('path/to/file.js')
    .transform('babelify')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('file.js')) // this is the output file name
    .pipe(gulp.dest('destination/directory/')); // and this is where it ends up
});
```

EDIT

I just realized I didn't address whether you *need* one or two tasks. You can technically do either, but the *best* way would be to have two separate tasks.

Comment: I'd prefer 1 task so that during development I can just do `gulp watch` to watch all folders I need

Comment: To clarify, I'm talking about the number of tasks your watch task will call. If you look at my second example, it's one gulp task that will watch two directories and fire off a different task for each.

Comment: I think I need something like your 2nd example, except 1 will be a `gulp.watch` one should be a call to start the watchify task. How might I do the later?

Comment: @JiewMeng That pastebin will only work if you have a task title 'watchify'. Regardless, if this helped you fix your issue, please upvote or select it as the correct answer. If you have more questions, comment them, and I'll do my best to answer.